# Hard-coded strings vs Resource file

Tags: .net, asp.net

As the title says then the question is relative simple however I cant decide whether a resource file with strings in is better than hard-coded strings... Whats your opinion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Main advantage is in localisation. Performance wise resources have a little more overhead but really not much of an issue.

If I am not worried at all about localisation then I would use **constants** (and not hard-coded strings).

Comment: Does it make sense to store the view my actionresult in the controller should return in a constant, if the view path is going to be used more than once in the actionresult? (ASP.NET MVC)

Comment: Yes, do not use resources for it. Resource only make sense for UI text and messages so that can be localised. This is purely code related so use constants. **I actually set the view name on the model as an attribute.**

Comment: Yea.. My first thought was to use the Resource file to store UI text/messages in that should be returned from my controllers (Actionresults). - To return to the "constant string" thing.. it makes no sense to use constant strings to store the viewname if its only used once in the actionresult right?

Comment: "It makes no sense to use constant strings to store the viewname if its only used once in the actionresult right?" I agree and I would probably do that myself but generally it is believed that using constants will make it more readable so some people would recommend constants even though it is used only once.

Comment: I see.. And the UI text/message, would you store them in a resource file or hard-code them? To use constants for those doesn't make much sense or is it about localization that you do store them in constants?

Comment: I am not much of UI developer so do not normally wouldnt do that kind of stuff but as I said, if I am not worried about localisation, I would use constants.

Comment: Alright.. think I'll go with constants then.. Seems to be a bit easier to find the strings etc. than if they were hard-coded into the code. Thanks for the answer and help!

Answer (score 3):

Have a realistic look at your application.

Reasons for resource files:

- Do you support multiple languages? If yes, you will use resource files.
- You are using a mid-size or bigger application and want to use the same Strings all over your web application? => Use resource files and get strong typed access to all your strings application wide

Reasons for hard-coded strings:

- Are you using a small application that will most likely not grow much more and localization is most certain not going to happen. => Hard-Coded Strings

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the web config file (so a resource file).
Hard-coded strings could be duplicated across your code and are much more difficult to "find and replace".  Hence, you are prone to error if you have the same hard coded string across any application be it asp.net, C#, vb.net etc.

If you have a resource file with a central place that stores connection information you will sleep better at night.  Your other option is to use some sort of constant and reuse that constant across your pages.